# Attendees of the event are not visible when importing an event ICalendar file into android calendar app

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, icalendar, android-calendar

I am forwarding a calendar event with multiple attendees as an iCalendar file attachment via email, importing the file in android native calendar application is showing all event details except the attendees added to the event while creation and when same file is imported in MS Outlook it is showing all the attendees.

Is there any other file format or file creation approach i should use for forwarding the event via email which will import all attendees of the event in android native calendar.

For creating iCalendar file i have used below approaches :

1. ICal4j library: http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page
2. BiWeekly library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biweekly/

But the result is same for both, Also the attendees are not visible while importing the same icalendar file to the google calendars.